# MySQL Create Index Semantics: Clustered vs. Nonclustered?

Tags: mysql, index, clustering

I'm new to databases and specifically MySQL, so pardon me if this is a simple question.

I'm trying to make sense of what happens with MySQL when I call `CREATE INDEX`. I know that primary keys are unique and correspond to a clustered index but what happens if I have a table where I have no primary key defined and create an index. I know by default the data structure is a B-tree but it's not clear if this corresponds to a clustered or nonclustered index in the typical sense.

Specifically I have a table that that has four columns as integers:

sales(item_id, time, price, location_id)

The only column that has unique values is time. If I create this table and then later run `CREATE INDEX dx ON sales(item_id);` what happens?

From [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-index-types.html) I'm lead to believe that when I create the table without the primary key, because time is unique that is the clustered index and so I'm creating a non-clustered index on item_id.

My questions are: is this correct? If so how can I create a *clustered* index on a non-unique column in MySQL?

Comment: If you're using a field with datatype time, then you should declare it as `field_name TIME NOT NULL`, then put a `UNIQUE` constraint in there. You should **not** use a field called `time` (or any other SQL reserved word). Time in MySQL can go down to the microsecond - unlikely that you'll get any dupes - declare as [TIME(6)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fractional-seconds.html) - see [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=a6d3686b6c38a6731b359659828ec897) for how this works! p.s.welcome to the forum!

Answer (score 1):

(This assumes you are using `ENGINE=InnoDB.)

Your table *must* have a primary key:  You have 3 choices:

1. (preferred)  You explicitly provide such.
2. There is a `UNIQUE` index with non-null column(s).  (Sloppy, just make it the PK)
3. (not a good option)  A hidden PK will be provided.

The PK *will* be clustered and unique.  That is the only choice for a pk in MySQL.

No other index can be clustered.  Again, that is by-definition.

There are 3 choices for structure of an index:

- (the most common) B+Tree.  (Everything else in this answer is B+Tree)
- `FULLTEXT` -- for searching for words in text
- `SPATIAL` -- for 2-dimensional searches, such as geographic

> sales(item_id, time, price, location_id)

Perhaps you need `PRIMARY KEY(item_id, time)`.  But that assumes you will never have two sales for the same item at exactly the same `time`.

So, it might be safer to have a 5th column:

```
id INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(id)
```

Let's see the `SELECTs`; from them we can decide what secondary index(es) you need.  Or do it yourself [*here*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql) .

> My questions are: is this correct? If so how can I create a clustered index on a non-unique column in MySQL?

That is a trick that very few people have discovered.  Once you have something that is unique (such as the 5th column, above), do this instead of the PK above:

```
PRIMARY KEY(time, id),
INDEX(id)
```

Now, even it `time` is not unique, the PK is clustered and unique because of `id` tacked on.  `AUTO_INCREMENT` does not require more than "being the first column in some index".